# How to count unique _id with ObjectId field in mongodb using Java driver 3.4+?

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to count documents unique _id with ObjectId field.
My documents are like:
[image]

So, I need to count these documents by unique _id and then replace everyone using replaceOne method (without touching _id of the document, because [_id field is immutable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/#update-documents)) to another documents.

I know that I can realize it with a few ways:

1) Using Iterator of FindIterable to get the count of the documents:

```
FindIterable findIterable = collection.find(Filters.eq("_id" (this is field), ... (but how I need to write value here if each document has unique _id?) ));
        Iterator iterator = findIterable.iterator();
        int count = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            count++;
        }
```

2) or simply create variable as `long count = collection.count(Document.parse("_id : (this is field) " + ...(but how I need to write value here if each document has unique _id?)));`

Correct me, please, or advise me the way how can I count these documents properly by unique _id to replace then? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Ids are unique by design, so the number of unique _ids is equal to the number of documents in the collection. Or in other words: use `collection.count()`

Comment: @mtj, thanks. Seems that it works simply like `long count = collection.count();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @mtj,

> Ids are unique by design, so the number of unique _ids is equal to the
>   number of documents in the collection. Or in other words: use
>   `collection.count()`